# Mute voice recognition bleep in Bluetooth Earpiece Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, voice-recognition, android-audiomanager, headset

I'm trying to get continuous voice recognition to work for a custom app on Android, using an [ML18 bluetooth headset (by plantronics)](http://www.plantronics.com/uk/product/ml18). I've managed to get rid of the beep produced by my phone by using the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701432/continues-speech-recognition-beep-sound-after-google-search-update) and managed to route all other media to my bluetooth device using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681085/android-voice-recognition-through-bluetooth).

However my bluetooth device is still beeping every time I call `SpeechRecognizer.startListening`.

Is there something I can do about this, or is this possibly hardwired into the software of the bluetooth device?

If you want to see specific sections of code, let me know. I do not think much of it is relevant however, as the two links above already cover the code that seems most relevant to me. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So based on the comment below, I've modified my code into the following:

The start listening simply mutes all stream but the alarm stream (undone by unmuting all streams again).

```
public void startListening() {
    if (canListen) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting Listening");
        Intent recognizerIntent = createRecognizerIntent();
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            ((AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).setStreamSolo(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The Bluetooth receiver does this when the device is connected:

```
    AudioManager localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
    localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

And then in the `ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED` it sets the mode to `AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL`.

Currently the behaviour is as follows:
When I first start the app and connect the bluetooth device, as well as trigger the continuous recognition loop, all works as expected. Yet after a first reply has been uttered (using TTS), the beep returns... Again, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can probably show your code. The beep is played over STREAM_VOICE probably in sco modo, so you need to mute that stream as well, not just STREAM_MUSIC.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Hmm ok so that seemed to work for a little bit, but then it didn't after a short while (updated my question to reflect this new information)

Comment: Ok, that's google thing. I would use pocketsphinx for android, it doesn't have any beeps and even more efficient for continuous recognition.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Hmm that actually looks pretty cool and from what I can see it happens locally on the phone?

Comment: Yes, it's fully offline.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I've tried pocketsphinx - correct me if I am wrong - it's mainly good for limited grammers or language models. It os not so suitable for full dictation.

Comment: @RonenRabinovici Unfortunately that was also my conclusion. Do you maybe have alternatives/solutions for this annoying sound bug?

Comment: @MrHug - I have no experience with bluetooth sorry