# Android Speech Recognizer with Bluetooth Microphone

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've been writing a chat app to work with bluetooth headsets/earphones.
So far I've been able to record audio files via the mic in a bluetooth headset and
I've been able to get Speech-to-text working with the Android device's built in microphone, using RecogniserIntent etc.

But I can't find a way of getting SpeechRecogniser to listen through the Bluetooth mic.Is it even possible to do so, and if so, how?

Current Device: Samsung Galax

Android Version: 4.4.2

Edit: I found some options hidden in my tablets settings for the Speech Recognizer, one of these is a tick box labeled "use bluetooth microphone" but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: I've found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681085/android-voice-recognition-through-bluetooth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question so I'm posting it for others to use:

In order to get speak recognition to work with a Bluetooth Mic you first need to get the device as a BluetoothHeadset Object and then call .startVoiceRecognition() on it, this will set the mode to Voice recognition.

Once finished you need to call .stopVoiceRecognition().

You get the BluetoothHeadset as such:

```
private void SetupBluetooth()
{
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy)
        {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)
            {
                btHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
            }
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile)
        {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                btHeadset = null;
            }
        }
    };
    btAdapter.getProfileProxy(SpeechActivity.this, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

}
```

Then you get call startVoiceRecognition() and send off your voice recognition intent like so:

```
private void startVoice()
{
    if(btAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        for (BluetoothDevice tryDevice : pairedDevices)
        {
            //This loop tries to start VoiceRecognition mode on every paired device until it finds one that works(which will be the currently in use bluetooth headset)
            if (btHeadset.startVoiceRecognition(tryDevice))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    recogIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recogIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    recog = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(SpeechActivity.this);
    recog.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener()
    {
       .........
    });

    recog.startListening(recogIntent);
}
```