# How to get Bluetooth Headset to work with SpeechRecognizer in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, speech-to-text

I really hope someone can help...
After plowing through loads of posts on the topic for days, both on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, I still haven't been able to get speech recognition to work with a Bluetooh Headset mic.
Speech recognition works perfectly fine with the smartphone mic.

I've tried the following elaborate solution from Hoan Nguyen: 
[Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590) by using parts of code.

Then decided to try the solution from
[Android Speech Recognizer with Bluetooth Microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086403/android-speech-recognizer-with-bluetooth-microphone)
which looks straightforward, but isn't working...

I'm using Android 6.0.1 with the latest Google apps installed.

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong or offer a working solution, I would really (REALLY) appreciate it...

Thanks!

====================

Comment: Ok, I just figured out the solution after some trial and error. Combining the code from Owen Ryan and Hoan Nguyen works perfectly, BUT ... my headset requires a button press ONCE for it to go into voice recognition mode. This was a major part of the problem all along... never knew that. Posted here, just in case someone else comes across the same issue.

Comment: Hey there, I have same issue right now, and unfortunately I haven't figured out yet :(. Do you mind can you share your code with me? Please help!!!